# Angular - how to "exit" a component?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Let's imagine I have a component that requires authentification (in fact some instance of that component need an authentication, other do not depending on "id" route instance variable) :

```
ngOninit() {
const id = +this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
this.isSecured = requiresAuthentication(id);

if (this.isSecured && !this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}

//very private data loading code
```

The problem is the rest of my code is always executed (which is fine if this component isn't secured or the user is logged in). But when the "if" condition is true (when navigate to login page), the rest of my code in the ngOninit() method still executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(this.isSecured && this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
  // sensitive stuff
} else {
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your pattern to validate the session or authentication of a user. The ideal pattern proposed by Angular is not to assemble the components if the access condition is not met.

For example:

```
class UserToken {}
class Permissions {
  canActivate(user: UserToken, id: string): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}

@Injectable()
class CanActivateTeam implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private permissions: Permissions, private currentUser: UserToken) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean>|Promise<boolean>|boolean {
    return this.permissions.canActivate(this.currentUser, route.params.id);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'team/:id',
        component: TeamCmp,
        canActivate: [CanActivateTeam]
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [CanActivateTeam, UserToken, Permissions]
})
class AppModule {}
```

- More info: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate
- Here is a more elegant example: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/route_guards.html

Comment: The problem is : with the id route parameter, I use it to load data from REST API, so that I can know if that specific id requires some authentication. So some code in that component needs to be executed. But I haven't used guard for some time now so it might still work

Comment: But you can pass this parameter to the "CanActivate" service and it will be responsible for validating whether or not it loads the component.